Download a large file with WebClient.UploadValues in parts
I need to upload a file that requires authentication which I provide via form data with WebClient.UploadValues
The problem is when I download a large file, the application pool is returned due to a memory limit.
The ideal solution is to split the answer into parts, but I haven't found documentation on how to do that
who can help
Thanks in advance

How are you downloading the file? I suggest using TransMitFile, since it does not load the whole file into memory, but reads + streams the file to the client, and does not load the whole file into memory, but reads the file in chunks for you, thus saving lots of memory.

Can you give me full code how to do it with HttpResponse.TransmitFile
Thanks
